# Dead branch in if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, case, naming

I'm writing this code where you give the the program a name.

Java is telling me that the else in the statement is never used when it should be used if the variable "isACoolGuy" is false.

```
if (isACoolGuy = true){
        System.out.println("Thank you for this name... "+ name);
    }else if(isACoolGuy = false){    
        System.out.println("Okay im changing my name since you are an idiot");
        name = name = "jack";
        System.out.println("My name is "+ name + " now");
```

There is a switch statement earlier that should change the "isACoolGuy" Boolean to false.

```
case "name":
            System.out.println("You are an a******");
            isACoolGuy = false;
            break;
```

Comment: you're using an assignment operator `=` in your if condition when you should be using a comparison operator `==`.

Comment: dnault's comment also applies to the elseif

Comment: This is (one reason) why you shouldn't explicitly compare boolean values to true or false. If you'd used `if (isACoolGuy)` and `else if (!isACoolGuy)`, you wouldn't have accidentally created the issue.

Comment: Just use `else`, if it fails the `if(isACoolGuy)`  test, then `! isACoolGuy` must be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your if is wrong

```
if (isACoolGuy == true){
        System.out.println("Thank you for this name... "+ name);
    }else if(isACoolGuy == false){
        System.out.println("Okay im changing my name since you are an idiot");
        name = "jack";
        System.out.println("My name is "+ name + " now");
```

or better

```
if (isACoolGuy){
        System.out.println("Thank you for this name... "+ name);
    }else if(!isACoolGuy){
        System.out.println("Okay im changing my name since you are an idiot");
        name =  "jack";
        System.out.println("My name is "+ name + " now");
```

and the most correct way in your case is to skip the else if and replace it with single else like this

```
if (isACoolGuy){
        System.out.println("Thank you for this name... "+ name);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Okay im changing my name since you are an idiot");
        name =  "jack";
        System.out.println("My name is "+ name + " now");
```

And some theory

isACoolGuy= true means assign true value to isACoolGuy variable . 
Using it inside an if always returns true
isACoolGuy == true checks if the variable isACoolGuy has true value. 
It's comparation

Inside an if you can skip comparing boolean values since if has the following format

```
if(true)
{

}
```

so If(isACoolGuy) is similar to if(isACoolGuy==true)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had entirely forgotten about the == vs = thing. And thank you for the tricks and tips for if and else they were giving me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if it's true, you are assigning isACoolGuy to true and hence it always evaluates to true.

```
 if (isACoolGuy = true){
```

Instead use

```
 if (isACoolGuy == true){
```

Better use:-

```
if (isACoolGuy)
```

Comment: if you're going to fix that you should fix the elseif as well.

Comment: 1) `iif`; 2) `if (isACoolGuy) {` would be better. (Although I haven't DV'd myself)

Answer (score 0):

To check the condition should use `==` not `=` it's for assignement, like this `if(isACoolGuy == true)`.
Try to remove second condition `if(isACoolGuy == false)` is not necessasry, it's enough to have key word `else` like this:

```
  isACoolGuy = true;  
  ...
  if (isACoolGuy){ // the positive control
    System.out.println("Thank you for this name... "+ name);
 }else{    // otherwise negative
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `if (condition == true)` is bad style. Just use `if (condition)`.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou I think so but the OP wrote like this