# Hangman Java Game Printing Both Wrong and Correct Guesses

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm doing my first programming language, Java, and I am having trouble getting correct guesses to print correctly. When a wrong letter is entered, it prints "wrong!" but when a correct letter is guessed, it prints both "Correct!" and "Wrong!"...any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)
The words are pulled from an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman! Below you can find the rules of the game.");
    //Welcome message
    System.out.println(); 
    //Spacing
    System.out.println("How to play:");
    System.out.println(); 
    //Spacing
    System.out.println("Hangman is a word guessing game. Guess the word by suggesting letters within a certain number of guesses.");
    System.out.println("The word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, representing each letter of the word.");
    System.out.println("If you guess a letter correctly, it replaces a dash and you can continue to guess until the word is uncovered.");
    System.out.println("However, if you guess wrong you lose a try. You have a maximum of 5 tries. After guessing 10 words, you win! Good luck!");
    //Rules of game
    System.out.println(); 
    //Spacing
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Scanner created
    String[] intro = {"after", "think", "could", "thank", "round", "clump", "plane", "beach", "towel", "tiger", "goat", "monkey", "house"};
    String[] beginner = {"around", "amount", "grown", "focus", "cedar", "flute", "unicorn", "fruit", "basket", "burger", "chips", "juice"};
    String[] intermediate = {"about", "bring", "clean", "mother", "locker", "hunter", "drink", "eight", "spray", "untie", "cents"};
    String name;
    int age;
    //Variables initialized
    System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
    //Prompt for name
    name = in.next();
    //Input for name
    System.out.println("Please enter your age:");
    //Prompt for age
    age = in.nextInt();
    //Input for age

    if (age >= 4 && age < 7){
    System.out.println("You have been placed in the Intro level!"); 
    Random rand = new Random();
    //Random created    
    int randomWord = rand.nextInt(12)+0;
    //Stores the position of array
    String word2guess = intro[randomWord];
    //String is the value stored in the generated position of array    
    char[] word2Char = word2guess.toCharArray();
    //Stores the word in a char array
    char[] wordLength = new char [word2Char.length];
    //Creates an array for word length
    for (int i = 0; i < word2Char.length; i++){
        wordLength[i] = '_';
    }
    //Replaces each letter of the word with an underscore
    for (int i = 0; i < word2Char.length; i++){
    System.out.print(wordLength[i] + " ");
    }
    //Prints the word in underscore format with a space between each letter
    int wrongGuesses = 0;
    int correctGuesses = 0;
    boolean letterFound = false;
    boolean nextWord = true;
    while (nextWord){
    while(correctGuesses != word2Char.length){
    System.out.println();
    //Spacing
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter:");
    char guess = in.next(".").charAt(0);
    //Input for only ONE letter
    for (int i = 0; i < word2Char.length; i++){
            if (guess == word2Char[i]){
               wordLength[i] = word2Char[i];
               letterFound = true;
               break;
            }else{
                letterFound = false;
            }
        }
           if(letterFound == false && wrongGuesses <= 4){
                wrongGuesses++;
                System.out.println("Wrong! You have "+ (5 - wrongGuesses)+" attempts remaining. Please try again.");
           }else{
               correctGuesses++;
               System.out.println("Correct!");
           }


    for (int i = 0; i < word2Char.length; i++){
        System.out.print(wordLength[i] + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    //Spacing
     if (correctGuesses == word2Char.length){
         System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the word. The word was: "+word2guess);
         nextWord = true;
     }
     if (wrongGuesses == 5){
       System.out.println();
       //Spacing
       System.out.println("Game Over! You have no attempts remaining. The word was: "+word2guess);
       nextWord = false;
       break;

      }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word2Char.length; i++){
        if (guess == word2Char[i]){
           wordLength[i] = word2Char[i];
           letterFound = true;
           correctGuesses++;
           System.out.println("Correct!");
        }


    }
       if(!letterFound){
        wrongGuesses++;
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
       }
```

Needs to be this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word2Char.length; i++){
                if (guess == word2Char[i]){
                   wordLength[i] = word2Char[i];
                   letterFound = true;
                   break;
                }else{
                    letterFound = false;
                }
            }
               if(letterFound == false){
                    wrongGuesses++;
                    System.out.println("Wrong!");
               }else{
                   correctGuesses++;
                   System.out.println("Correct!");
               }
```

The issue was that in the for loop, even if `letterFound` was true, the loop would keep on checking each char. It would've only worked if someone guessed the last char correctly. So what I did was add a `break` statement so that whenever `letterFound` is true, the for loop exits.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I added the curly brackets but it did not print "wrong" when an incorrect letter was entered, instead it just asked the user to enter another letter. Regards, Jason.

Comment: @icewolf461: this is bad Java: `if (foo = false) {` because foo will be **assigned** to be false ***always***. Instead do `if (!foo) {`

Comment: Unless you're purposely always setting solved to false, your fix also has the wrong operator.

Comment: It's giving an error that "solved" wasn't initialized, do I make it true or false by default?

Comment: @icewolf461 booleans should always be `false` on initialization.

Comment: Okay so it works up until a correct letter is entered. e.g: Guess 1: Wrong! Guess 2: Wrong! Guess 3: Correct! Guess 4: Please enter a letter (it doesn't say Wrong!"

Comment: Can you post your full code? E.g. the entire class; I feel like there's a lot more errors than just the one in my answer. I can't run your code, so I can't know for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Posted it in the first post.

Comment: @icewolf461 Found the problem; see my edited answer; it fixed the problem for me. Sorry for all the incomplete info.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam Thanks. Now I'm trying to let it prompt the user to guess another word after successfully guessing the previous word. (Up to 10 words). So I created another Boolean at the beginning of code (see above I updated it) but it's stuck on running with a blank space in the console. :/

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in java, this branch would never be used:

```
if (solved = false) {
    wrongGuesses++;
}
```

Please change that to

```
    if (solved == false) {
        wrongGuesses++;
        System.out.println("Wrong!");//And then add the wrong print out here
    }
```

I would like you to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406303/dead-branch-in-if-else-statement/34406332) and [here too](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236468)